# ORA-21700 when using polimorphism in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a hierarchy of Oracle object types, for example:

```
parent_t 
child_1_t under parent_t
child_2_t under parent_t
```

I also have a collection type of parent_t objects:

```
col_t is table of parent_t
```

And a function that returns this collection. The returned collection may contain child_1_t or child_2_t objects.

This works fine in PL/SQL, if called this way:

```
l_col := fun();
-- process l_col
```

However, if called from SQL:

```
select * from table(fun());
```

I get ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete.

If I change the signature of the function to return only a collection of child objects, everything works fine.

Is there any way to make it work in SQL with the signature of collection of parent objects?

Comment: try to add `TABLE` expression `select * from table(fun())`

Comment: thank you for spotting this, actually I had TABLE all the time, I just did not put it in the question

Comment: I think, you should try creating a very similar, [pipelined function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions) to be allowed to query from it in SQL context.

Comment: Using pipelined function does not change much. However, I created a separate class hierarchy and a new function that uses this new hierarchy, and the SQL works without errors. So I guess I have a problem with the initial type hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick test script for the scenario that you described
and it works as expected. maybe something is wrong with your function or types and I hope this working script helps you

```
select * from table(my_foo);

    ID
1   1
2   2

create or replace type parent_t as object(
id int
) not final;

create or replace type child_1_t  under parent_t
(name varchar2(10));

create or replace type child_2_t  under parent_t
(descr varchar2(10));

create or replace type collection_parent_t as table of parent_t;

create or replace function my_foo return collection_parent_t
as
  t1 child_1_t;
  t2 child_2_t;
  res collection_parent_t := collection_parent_t();
begin

  t1 :=  child_1_t(1, '1');
  t2 :=  child_2_t(2, '2');

  res.extend;
  res(res.count) := t1;

  res.extend;
  res(res.count) := t2;

  return res;
end;
```

Comment: I made the same tests with simplified objects and it works as well. I dropped and recreated my initial object hierarchy and it started working as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had those problems, because my object types got corrupted in some way. I dropped the types, recreated them and now everything works as expected.